# "Had been engaged when they married" vs. "were married" vs. "had married"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, past-perfect, simple-past

Which of the sentences below are grammatically correct?

> 1. The couple had been engaged for five years when **they married**.
> 2. The couple had been engaged for five years when **they were married**.
> 3. The couple had been engaged for five years when **they had married**.

Only (1) sounds correct to me, but I am unable to explain why (2) and (3) are grammatically wrong.

Comment: @simchona- Was the question closed because there were too many items in it? I am just trying to understand if my sentences are grammatically correct, and I didn't mean to post an off topic one.

Comment: sorry, I meant to left a comment. Each of your questions should have its own post, and also make sure you emphasize your thoughts on each(like "I think this tense should have been used because...") so it doesn't sound like proofreading.

Comment: @simchona- I updated my question based on your comment. Could you please re-open it if you feel the question is valid? thanks!

Comment: I prefer *The two were engaged for five years* **before** *they were married*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two are grammatical. In the first, *married* is the past tense of *marry*, and is here used intransitively.

In the second, *they were married* is a passive construction, and *married* is the past participle of *marry*. Although it is passive, the agent is not mentioned, but we can reasonably assume that they were married **by** a priest, or **by** a government official.

The third is ungrammatical because the past perfect construction describes a past event that precedes another. It is clear in this case that the wedding took place only **after** they had been engaged, and not before.

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer sentence 1.
The use of the past perfect continuous in the first section refers to a situation that was true for a period of time prior to some other event; the use of the simple past in the second section provides the other event as expected.

The use of "were married" in the second half of sentence two may be interpreted as simple past (passive) by people who believe that a priest does the marrying, and the couple just stands there and lets it happen to them, so it may pass muster for some.  However, the phrase *when they were married* can also be interpreted as "During the time period in which they were married", which leaves one wondering why they were both engaged and married at the same time.

Using "had married" (past perfect) to describe an event that happened after another event is wrong; past perfect is for events that precede another event.

Comment: I see no continuous constructions in any of the sentences.

Comment: You are quite right, sir.  I should have (and now have) said "past progressive".

Comment: _Progressive_ is another term for _continuous_. Such constructions are made by combininng the _-ing_ form of the main verb with an appropriate form of the verb _be_. For example, _They married_ is in the past tense, but _They were marrying_ is a past continuous (or progressive) construction.

Comment: What form then is "they were married", as in "they existed in a state of marriage" (as opposed to "a marriage event happened to them")?

Comment: In that case, _married_ is an adjective, acting as the subject predicative, or complement, of _were_.

Comment: Would "I was married for 20 years" qualify as past progressive, past perfect, simple past, or ... ?

Comment: _Was_ is past tense and _married_ is once again an adjective, filling the role of subject predicative. The sentence is no different grammatically from _I was single for 20 years_.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, feel *married* in these forms of sentences work like adjectives. Also, *I am interested* may be another example. They look like passive forms, but their intransitive character supports my opinion that they are adjectives.